# Moving binary logs in MySQL to a different hard disk

Tags: mysql

This question is about MySQL binary logs.

We need to move a binary log to a different hard disk.

What is the configuration change required in MySQL?

Currently binary logs go into the same folder as the ibdata and there is a replication slave running which needs the binary logs.

Answer (score 7):

Changing the log-bin works. BUT you need to copy the log-bin files first to the new location and modify the index file. If you dont'do this  you will break your remote slave with the error:

Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'

More info here:
http://freebsd.down-to-details.com/sys-admin/relocating-moving-mysql-binlogs/

Comment: how about if it is a multi-master replication set up. does the same apply in the link posted

Comment: When I did this it was in the context of a master-master setup...but there should be no difference...

Answer (score 2):

From the way I read [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html), you can specify a path on the log-bin config.

> To enable the binary log, start the
>   server with the --log-bin[=base_name]
>   option. If no base_name value is
>   given, the default name is the value
>   of the pid-file option (which by
>   default is the name of host machine)
>   followed by -bin. If the basename is
>   given, the server writes the file in
>   the data directory **unless the basename
>   is given with a leading absolute path
>   name to specify a different directory**.
>   It is recommended that you specify a
>   basename; see Section C.5.8, “Known
>   Issues in MySQL”, for the reason.